# Windows incorrectly marks my drives as "System"

Tags: windows, backup

I want to back up my Windows system using System Image Backup (control panel - file history - system image backup).

Windows won't let me backup unless I include an external hard drive, and another internal hard drive, which makes the backup size prohibitive.

[image: http://imgur.com/OzX7Wan]

My C: drive is Windows that I want to back up.

My D: drive is another internal disk. That disk contains the EFI system partition. I used to be able to backup only the EFI system partition + Windows.

My P: drive has been used for File History once before, but File History is now turned off.

How do I tell Windows these drives are not system drives ?

Answer (score -1):

Windows backup will include any partition that is or was even only remotely related to the OS partition. If you want to image the partitions individually regardless of their interrelationship I recommend to use free Macrium. ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I

Comment: My question is about removing the "system" attributes on those drives, not about backing up.